# Issue with Chrome Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: google-chrome, 19.10, remote

I recently attempted to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 but encountered an issue. During the process, the upgrade froze with the following message: *lvm2-activation-generator activation generator failed*. I rebooted, but could no longer access my desktop. It would take me as far as allowing me to select a user and enter my password, but it would just immediately return me back to the login screen. After many failed attempts to try and recover from this error, I decided to just perform a fresh install of 19.10.

The fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10 went fine and had no issues whatsoever -- that is, until I installed **Chrome Remote Desktop**. After the next restart, I was encountering the exact same problem as before. I would be taken to the login screen, and could never proceed any further. I was able uninstall Chrome Remote Desktop via console, and success, system was functioning normal again!

Has anybody encountered a similar problem? Any suggestions to get Chrome Remote Desktop working with 19.10?

Comment: Just spun up a new box running 19.10 and am seeing the same. I've been seeing that after first setup and remote connection I'm able to connect. Afterwards I need  to move / remove ~/.conifg to log in locally again successfully. Commiseration rather than help, but you're not alone :)

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too.  Although I can work around the issue by first logging in via remote desktop, then it will allow me to log in via the console.

Found this which seems to be my issue:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9409642?hl=en&msgid=26555936:

> In my case the issue is due to a reboot or shutdown command from
>   remote session. This started the endless loop in the GUI login of the
>   device. To fix it log in remotely again in the affected device (it
>   works) than simply close the session without reboot or shutdown of the
>   affected device. Try now to log in.